# SQL Statement to work on a Microsoft Access Database which will get Top 5 Records but Skip the first 5

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

[image]I need help with an SQL Statement to work on a Micrsoft Access Database which has a table named Tasks. I would like to get Top 5 Records but skiping the first 5 records. 
I am therefore looking for an SQL equivalent of the .Skip() method in LINQ which will work on an Micrsoft Access Database.
I will need to put this query in a string variable

```
Dim myQuery As String
myQuery  = "Select *     "
```

Comment: What is your field for sorting? Can 2 records have the same sort field value?

Comment: I am sorting by ID

Comment: @FaheemAhmad - you can use a NOT IN subquery to exclude the first Top 5 from your Top 5 query - see my answer for sample SQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the top 10 in a subquery, and select the bottom 5 of that in an outer query.  Since you'd like the result sorted by `ID asc`, you can add another outer query for sorting:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  top (5) *
        from    (
                select  top (10) *
                from    YourTable
                order by
                        ID
                ) sub
        order by
                ID desc
        ) sub2
order by
        ID
```

Comment: @Andomar - many thanks for your solution. It gives me the result but the order is not correct. It orders the result by ID Desc, I would like the result to be Ordered by ID Asc.

Comment: @Andomar - I have added an image to my question to explain how I would like the results to look like.

Comment: Then you could add yet another query, to sort the last 5 results. I'll update the answer

Comment: I have tested solution suggested by Andomar again and it is now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just have to "reverse" the sorting in Andomar's SQL:

```
strSelectBooks = "Select Top 5 * From (Select Top 10 * From Tasks Where Person = 'Manager' Order By ID Desc) As Tasks10 Order By ID Asc"
```

Comment: Wouldn't this select the wrong rows in the right order?  I.e. bottom 5-10 instead of top 5-10.

Comment: I had to check with 100 records to be sure. The subquery returned 100-91. The main query then returned 91-95. In those orders. That seems correct to me according to the wording in the question, though not to the displayed example.

Comment: @Gustav - this (Select Top 5 * From (Select Top 10 * From Tasks Where Person = 'Manager' Order By ID Desc) As Tasks10 Order By ID Asc) gets records 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

Comment: Well, TOP is normally from the highest value and down.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the order won't work as you'd just get the top 5 again

I think you can get the next top 5 by doing a NOT IN first Top 5 as in

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM Tasks
WHERE (ID Not In 
    (SELECT TOP 5 ID FROM Tasks ORDER BY ID)
ORDER BY ID;
```

In VBA that would just look the same with line continuation ("_") and concatenation ("&")

```
myQuery  = "SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Tasks " & _
    "WHERE (ID Not In (SELECT TOP 5 ID FROM Tasks ORDER BY ID) " & _
    "ORDER BY ID"
```

**EDITED - Use a two step query and a temp table to speed up results 100 fold**

1. Make tmp table to store results of Top 5

`SELECT TOP 5 ID INTO tmpTop5 FROM Tasks ORDER BY ID;`

2. Exclude those results from second Top 5 query

`SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Tasks WHERE ID Not In (SELECT ID FROM tmpTop5) ORDER BY ID;`

Comment: This was my first thought as well, but for a large table it would, I guess, be painfully slow. Didn't test that, though.

Comment: Yes you're right @Gustav it is slow on big tables. Would any speedup occur if the query was predefined and "compiled"? as in `SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Tasks WHERE (ID Not In  (SELECT ID FROM qTop5IDs) ORDER BY ID;`

Comment: I don't think so, as simple as the subquery is. But I have no large suitable table to test with.